# Set a field value depending on itself and other fields

Tags: c#, api

I want an Enum Field that can be set either to its own value if it is not null or depending on another member value.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public class Test {
    public bool Foo { get; set; } = false;
    public TypeEnum Bar {
            set
            {
                Bar =  Bar ?? (Foo ? TypeEnum.Type1 : TypeEnum.Type2);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing that stops you from doing this, other than that you have to use the special identifier `value` to refer to the incoming value and that `TypeEnum` must be nullable for this to be meaningful in the first place. Do note that properties with "magic" setters like this (i.e. where the `get` does not return the same value as the `set`) tend to be more difficult to maintain due to violating the principle of least surprise. It can be more predictable to dedicate an explicit method to this, or another type entirely that uses `Test` as input.

Comment: Also, your property has no backing field that could store the a value. Assigning a value to the property itself in the setter will create a recursion. You are reading `Bar` in the assignment expression, which is not possible, because `Bar` has no getter. I suggest that you learn more about [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/properties).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think Jeroen was proposing in comment:

```
public class Test 
{
    public bool Foo { get; set; } = false;
    public TypeEnum? Bar { get; private set; }
    public void SetBarDependingOnFoo()
    {
        Bar =  Bar ?? (Foo ? TypeEnum.Type1 : TypeEnum.Type2);
    }
}
```

That would be a one-time-set, though, because it will keep the value once it is not `null` any more.

Of course you could write a custom setter on `Foo`, that resets `Bar` to `null` ... but now I am speculating on what you want.

Another way to do this would be a little different with a little different behaviour:

```
public class Test 
{
    public bool Foo { get; set; } = false;
    public TypeEnum Bar => Foo ? TypeEnum.Type1 : TypeEnum.Type2;
}
```

Here, the Value of `Bar` *always* depends on the current state of `Foo`.

---

> Let say Foo cannot be muted after set.

In that case, I'd question that this class makes sense, really. You may be wanting more of a "builder"...

```
public interface IBarBuilder
{
    IBarBuilder WithFoo(bool foo);
    TypeEnum Build();
}

public class BarBuilder: IBarBuilder
{
    private bool _myFoo = false;

    IBarBuilder IBarBuilder.WithFoo(bool foo)
    {
         _myFoo = foo;
         return this;
    }

    TypeEnum IBarBuilder.Build()
    {
         return _myFoo ? TypeEnum.Type1 : TypeEnum.Type2;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var builder = new BarBuilder().WithFoo(true);
TypeEnum myBar = builder.Build(); // from here use myBar
```

Or even much simpler (I assumed your actual usecase may be more complex): a factory method ("factory" is a little exagerated here):

```
public static TypeEnum GetBar(bool foo) => foo ? TypeEnum.Type1 : TypeEnum.Type2;
```

Comment: Let say Foo cannot be muted after set.

Comment: Foo could be `public bool Foo { get; }` or public `bool Foo { get; init; }` or, with C# 11, `public required bool Foo { get; init; }`. see [required modifier (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/required).

Comment: There are a lot of possibilites, going from there, yes. `Foo` could be a CTOR-Param ... the list goes on and on.